# it is possible to pass value to _ViewStart to my default _Layout for generating user menu

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a layout that is shared between other Area in my project.
User log to that site base on AD role each users has different menu to be generate.

I have a BD that has some data pre define name to generate label menu so where should i do my logic ? Since my default menu is shared base on **_ViewStart.cshtml** between Area who is re-direct to default **_Layout.cshtml** how can i obtain a model to **_Layout.cshtml*.

Basic example HomeController has the the default method Index() with View Index so basically i do all my logic inside HomeController. What about _Layout who is share across all Area that generate my menu where i am suppose to put my logic code so base on each role i create a model with all my data to that layout file.

So my second question would be how you pass value from **_ViewStart** into that default **_Layout**.

Sorry for my english if you guy don't understand i will try to reformulate.

Comment: Yes, please reformulate it. And you do not need several quotation marks.

Comment: i reformulate maybe still confuse but its hard to explain better hope someone could understand...

Comment: Put your logic to fill the model for the Layout inside an Action Filter, which will be executed for all actions.